# Count the squares

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

## Challenge

Origami (folding paper) is a creative form of art. As far as I know, master of Origami prefers square paper. Let's start from beginning - convert a rectangular paper to a square one.

So the paper is divided into squares. We remove the biggest square which shares one shorter edge with the current shape, step by step (see the picture below). And if the remaining part after one step is less or equal than `0.001 * (area of the original paper)`, the paper cannot be divided any further. It is possible that nothing remains at last.

Your task is to calculate how many squares are made during the process. The square in the last step that makes the paper unable to be divided is counted into the output.

Example (a paper of `1.350` width/height), output is 10:

[image: slice example]

## Input and Output

Input: width / height ratio for the rectangular paper, one decimal (or an integer without the dot) from `1.002` to `1.999` with a minimal step of `0.001`. You may also use any other reasonable format describing the ratio. Just mention it in your answer.

Output: square count, one integer.

## Example I/O

A mapping format is used to keep the page tidy, while your code doesn't need to support a list input nor to be a mapping function.

```
1.002 => 251
1.003 => 223
1.004 => 189
1.005 => 161
1.006 => 140
1.007 => 124
1.008 => 111
1.009 => 100
```

[List of all answers](http://pastebin.com/e4UfWpvd)

Thanks to @LuisMendo, here is the graph of answers.

[image: graph]

## Remarks

- This is a code-golf so shortest code wins
- Pay attention to standard loopholes
- It's your freedom to decide how to deal with input and output  but they should follow standard restrictions.

By the way...

- Comment if you have anything unclear about the challenge
- Personally I would suggest your answer contains a explanation if you are using a golfing language
- Thanks to @GregMartin, read his answer for a good mathematical explanation for the challenge.

## Example Code

Here is a ungolfed version of C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int f (double m)
{
    double n = 1, k = 0.001;
    int cnt = 0;
    k *= m;                       // the target minimum size
    while(m*n >= k)
    {
        m -= n;                   // extract a square
        if(n > m)
            std::swap(n, m);      // keep m > n
        ++ cnt;
    }
    return cnt;
}

int main()
{
    double p;
    std::cin >> p;
    std::cout << f(p);
    return 0;
}
```

All calculations related in the example code need an accuracy of 6 decimal digits, which is covered in `float`.

Comment: Can two numbers forming the ratio be used as inputs?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes, as your wish.

Comment: Neat challenge!

Comment: The list of answers produces a [nice graph](https://s23.postimg.org/5g3csodcr/untitled.png)

Comment: @LuisMendo, would you mind if I add your graph into the description?

Comment: @KeyuGan Of course, go ahead! Let me know if you need a version with some other format

Comment: Thinking the problem over, there seems to be a bug: 1x1.002 gives first a 1x1 square, leaving 500 0.002x0.002 squares, so the first result should be 501, not 251. While condition should be m*n>1e-6, I think. On mobile, so excuse lack of formatting...

Comment: @KenY-N It is because the challenge is not diving the paper into squares as many as you can. Squares are divided one by one. Consider about one 1x1 and 250 0.002x0.002 squares, the total area of 251 squares is 1.001, and the resting part is 0.001 which is smaller than the threshold mentioned in the challenge. (1.002*0.001=0.001002)

Comment: Ah, I see now. My misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 19 bytes

```
`SZ}y-htG/p1e-3>}x@
```

The input is an array with the two numbers defining the original ratio, such as `[1, 1.009]`. (It is not necessary that the numbers be sorted or that one of them be 1.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@58QHFVbqZtR4q5fYJiqa2xXW@Hw/3@0oY6CoZ6BgWUsAA)

#### Explanation

```
`        % Do...while loop
  S      %   Sort array. Takes 1×2 array as input (implicit) the first time
  Z}     %   Split array into its 2 elements: first the minimum m, then the maximum M
  y      %   Duplicate m onto the top of the stack. The stack now contains m, M, m
  -      %   Subtract. The stack now contains m, M-m
  h      %   Concatenate into [m, M-m]. This is the remaining piece of paper
  t      %   Duplicate
  G/     %   Divide by input, element-wise
  p      %   Product of array. Gives ratio of current piece's area to initial area
  1e-3>  %   True if this ratio exceeds 1e-3. In that case the loop continues
}        % Finally (execute after last iteration, but still within the loop)
  x      %   Delete last piece of paper
  @      %   Push current loop counter. This is the result
         % End (implicit)
         % Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>71 70 65 63 62 61 58</s> 56 bytes

Thanks to @xnor for a some ingenious improvements!

```hs
(n#m)e|e>n*m*1e3=0|n<m=m#n$e|d<-n-m=(d#m)e+1
n!m=n#m$n*m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@6@Rp5yrmVqTapenlatlmGpsa1CTZ5Nrm6ucp5Jak2Kjm6eba6uRAlKjbciVp5hrC1SvAlT7PzcxM0/BVqGgtCS4pMgnT0FFoTgjvxxIaRgaGBgpAgkDzf8A)

Comment: It think the `m==n` at the end can be `1>0` because it's the only possibility remaining. Or, maybe the cases could be rearranged to allow a bind here.

Comment: Actually, is the equality case needed? If `n>m` is expanded to `n>=m` and  the first check is written `e>m*n*1000`, that should give `1` for equality.

Comment: @xnor Good idea, thank you!

Comment: Moving around guards for 56: `(n#m)e|e>n*m*1e3=0|n<m=m#n$e|d<-n-m=(d#m)e+1;n!m=n#m$n*m`

Comment: Wow, using the `d<-n-m` as `otherwise` is really neat!!!

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```js
f=(m,n=!(k=m/1e3,c=0))=>m*n<k?c:(c++,m-=n)<n?f(n,m):f(m,n)
```

#### Test

```js
f=(m,n=!(k=m/1e3,c=0))=>m*n<k?c:(c++,m-=n)<n?f(n,m):f(m,n)

console.log(f(1.002))
console.log(f(1.003))
console.log(f(1.004))
console.log(f(1.005))
console.log(f(1.006))
console.log(f(1.007))
console.log(f(1.008))
console.log(f(1.009))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <s>64</s> 53 bytes

```
({t=1,#}//.{a_,b_}/;1000a*b>#:>Sort@{++t;a,b-a};t-1)&
```

An imperative (C-style) solution is exactly the same length:

```
(For[t=a=1;b=#,1000a*b>#,If[a>b,a-=b,b-=a];++t];t-1)&
```

Answer (score 2):

## C (GCC/Clang), <del>61</del> 59 bytes

```
c,k;f(m,n){for(k=m*n;m*n/k;m>n?(m-=n):(n-=m))++c;return c;}
```

Input is two integers (width & height) without dot, such as `f(1999,1000)`.

I hope someone could save one byte pushing C into the 58-byte club. ;)

Comment: Suggest removing the parentheses around `m-=n`

Answer (score 1):

## C, 59 bytes

```c
s,a,n=1e3;C(m){for(a=m;m*n>a;s++)m>n?m-=n:(n-=m);return s;}
```

[Try It online](https://tio.run/##NczBDoIwEATQO1/RkGh2pU2K3twUD3xJU8Fw2LVp8UT49oqKc5q8TCaYRwilZO21uHa4UA@My/hM4B0Tn6TzlJsGuZMbGydXEOMYKQ3zK4nKtJZJZsV@EsBqqdSWD0T61hy8jFAf7rVWx4g/jGlb/LWHiLvvn5aqtbTWnt8)

The input is an integer which is the width / height ratio in thousandths (eg. 1002 for 1.002:1).

#### Ungolfed version

```c
int C(int m)
{
    int n = 1000;
    int a = m;
    int s = 0;

    while (m * n > a)
    {
        if (m > n)
            m -= n;
        else
            n -= m;

        s++;
    }

    return s;
}
```